# Mac eclipse set workspace to dropxbox causes startup crash

Tags: eclipse, macos, crash, dropbox, startup

Eclipse was working fine until i decided to switch workspaces to my dropbox folder. After that, trying to launch eclipse would bring up the logo startup screen shortly followed by a crash saying "an error has occurred" with a log file to reference. I am pretty sure it's only when using dropbox as a workspace. I managed to get eclipse running again by going into terminal and using ./eclipse -clean. I then tested the problem again by switching to my desktop and switching back to dropbox (for workspaces) and eclipse would only fail to start when i had dropbox as the workspace. Anyone know why this is or how to fix this? Thank you

Macbook Pro early 2008
Mountain Lion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that dropbox hasn't renamed any binary files which have conflicted in the .metadata folder. I had this problem and that was the cause.

Comment: Find the files which have 'conflicted' appended to the end of them and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting just your project folder, not your entire workspace folder, in the Dropbox folder.  That is, put the folder that contains the .project file, not its parent folder that contains a .metadata directory.

(A better solution of course would be to use a proper software repository.  For example, [Git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion).  In this case, you could use it to not only backup and share your code, but maintain a record of your changes.)